# NPM Install without CD the folder

Tags: angular, powershell, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using Windows Powershell and a pipeline in order to create the package of the application that I must deploy.

This is my pipeline:
[image]

My issue regards the "npm install" command, because I don't want to CD the path where the package.json is stored. How to indicate where the "npm install" should be execute? I tried:

"npm --prefix C:\MyPath\Application\ClientApp install" but it returns this error

[image]

Comment: Make sure your path is wrapped in quotes (`"`) or that there are no spaces in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

```
npm install --prefix C:\MyPath\Application\ClientApp
```